# call .cs class file(c#) function from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have doubt regarding call .cs class file(C#) function from javascript
    My Code:
    I have class file(.cs) like call_cs_function_from_js

```
------------------------------------------------------------------


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace call_cs_function_from_js
{
    public class cal_lcs_function_from_js
    {
        public void getdata()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

### This is javascript code File:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function call(){
  cal_lcs_function_from_js.getdata();  //This way is not working 
  alert('called');
}
</script>
```

Here I want call getdata of cal_lcs_function_from_js from call()(means .js). call() invoked when button click.

Please Show me what are the other ways.

Comment: The code you've written wouldn't work in c# either. It's a method and as such you would need an instance of the class.

Comment: Off-topic and extremely nitpicky: apart from the fact that you're ignoring all case-conventions, why's your function named `getdata()` when it doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 5):

You can not call your C# function directly from your javascript code. As javascript runs on client side and your C# function resides on the server.
For that you have to create a Web Service, and call that service form your javascript using `Ajax`.

**UPDATE:**

1. First add the namespace `using System.Web.Services;` to your web page.
2. Add the following method to your page

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public string GetData()
   {
       return ("");
   }
   ```
3. Call the method using `Ajax`.

   $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/GetData",
           success: function (data) {
           });

Comment: What are you using at server side ASP.net web forms or MVC?

Comment: Hello Asif, my C# function is placed in class file(.cs) in Asp.net web page so i called like -------   function call() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "cal lcs function from js.cs/getdata"
            }).done(function () {
                alert('called');
            });
        }

Comment: But my function in class file(.cs) not in asp.net page and my doubt is how to set url

Comment: To be able to get call from the client side you must have a url. For that you need to create an ASP.net page or add your web method to an existing page. From that web method you can call you code.

Comment: can i send my simple code here if u free please try.Help me dude

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can call a C# function using javascript is if you're running the C# function within an ASP.NET page. Then you would use an ajax call from the javascript to call the ASP.Net page and retrieve the results of your function.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
function call(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/cal_lcs_function_from_js"
  }).done(function() { 
    alert('called');
  });
}
```

where "/cal_lcs_function_from_js" is a page running in ASP.net on the same web server as the javascript file is being run from.

Comment: No sir,i want place my function in .cs class file.And call the .cs class file function from javascript function

Comment: This is not possible. The only way you can do this is how I mentioned above.

Comment: I am trying this ,later i wl inform u sir.