# call class file(.cs in c#) function from javascript and helps how to write Ajax+Webservices

Tags: c#, javascript

Here my simple sample code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace PopUpFromCsFile
{
    public class PopUpWindow
    {
        public void PopUpFromCsFile()
        {
         string str1 = "<script> $.ajax({" +
                     "type: 'GET'," +
                      "url: 'Service/Class1.cs/callfromjs'," +
                        "data: '{}'," + "success: function () { getDetails(); } " +
                        "});</script>";

        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script1", str1);

        }
        [WebMetod]
        public string  CallFromJs()
        {
            return "santosh";
        }

      public void getDetails()
       {
        string str = "<script>alert('Hai');</script>";
        System.Web.UI.Page page = (System.Web.UI.Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script2", str);
       }
    }
}
```

### Explanation

In PopUpFromCsFile(), I wrote code for Ajax+WebMethod. Is Url path is correct,Here I am unable to call  getDetails() from script.

Comment: This question is asked at least once a day. See the answer to your own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680409/call-cs-class-filec-function-from-javascript and many others. In brief, setup a HTTP handler of some sort (page, controller, web service, WCF endpoint, etc) to receive your client request and invoke the appropriate server method.

Comment: @Tim wait, isn't this the same exact question asked twice?!?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi - yeah, I realized that after I found the link. This is the same question by the same person, and there is a good answer to the question (web method + AJAX). Plus, there are a dozen good links just in the "related" column.

Comment: @Tim SO makes me sad sometimes. RIP documentation, research, and experimentation.

Comment: @Tim  -- I am using web method + AJAX for class file function but it is not working.

Comment: @user1402972 - Then you need to post that code and the specific problem. I don't see any AJAX or a web method in your code sample.

Comment: @Tim: Look My code with ajax+Webservixes . Guide me if i have in wrong route

Answer (score 2):

You can't. A `.cs` is a C# source code file, and cannot (from *any* language) be used as-is. You must compile it to a DLL.

And once you do, you can't communicate with a DLL from JavaScript. JavaScript is sandboxed into your browser. You'd need to write (and install on every client PC) a browser extension to interface with a native DLL.

You need to rewrite the C# code as JavaScript.

Comment: i thought maybe he wants to call a c# function from a webbrowser control !!

Comment: @UnLoCo Honestly, I have no clue what he wants any more.